# Installed OpenCV but no module found "cv2" in IDLE

Tags: python, opencv, installation

I have been trying to install OpenCV for ages now and finally I succeeded using this tutorial: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/05/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-3-5/.

However, whenever I try to import cv2 in IDLE, it is not found but I am certain I installed OpenCV.

The cv2.so file exists at:
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2.so

I believe it may have something to do with the interpreter but I am not sure how to fix it. In terminal, when I try importing it, it works. I included the terminal message to prove it.

[image: Terminal Message]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i found the answer! after you activate the virtual environment with:

```
work on cv
```

type this on the terminal to open the IDLE with the current virtual environment

```
python -c "from idlelib.PyShell import main; main()"
```

or

```
python -m idlelib
```

and it will do the trick!

Comment: Thank you!!! It worked like a charm! Could you explain to me however what those commands do? And will I have to run those commands each time I want to use opencv in IDLE? Cheers!

Comment: You are welcome! 
Sure. You need to understand virtual environments first. By typing work on  cv you are activating the virtual environment (that openCv is installed on).  Now when you type python on your terminal you are actually using this python (virtual environment) installed with openCV . Idle is a build in module of python. So python -m idlelib opens the IDLE with the version of your terminal which happens to be the activated virtual environment with opencv. You can write a bash script that when you double click it does this for you. if you don't know how ask.

Answer (score 0):

Dumb approach but does your IDLE run the same python environment as your terminal?

Comment: i think you messed up somewhere here :

Important: Inspect this output closely. If you see /usr/local/bin/python3  then you are correctly using the Homebrew version of Python. However, if the output is /usr/bin/python3  then you are incorrectly using the system version of Python.

If you find yourself using the system version of Python instead of the Homebrew version you should:

Ensure Homebrew installed without error.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check whether IDLE and terminal run the same environment. Python3 is definitely installed correctly with Homebrew. I've found a workaround where I edit in IDLE and run the script in the terminal by doing the commands:

workon cv –> cd /Directory_of_py_file –> python filename.py

Comment: There are different versions of IDLE installed for each Python version. Depending on how you installed Python on Mac OS X, you may find different folders in /Applications. Look for a Python 3.n (n = 5 or 4) folder with an IDLE in it. Or, from a terminal command line. The problem is that IDLE is using your system environment and when you type workon cv on terminal you use the virtual environment.. Your workaround is how usually someone run python scripts with multiple environments. I suggest you to look into Sublime or Atom for Editors with a Python syntax plug in.