# import cv2 doesn't give error on command-Prompt but error on IDLE on Windows 10, Python 3.6.4

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-3.6

I have Installed Python 3 (32bit) on Windows.

[image: My error screen is here]
I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35466429/opencv-for-python-3-5-1/42540015#42540015), but I can't install cv2 using
 `pip install  opencv_python-3.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl`  and it gives error as

`opencv_python-3.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

when I tried Python shell, and run the command `import cv2` it doesn't give error,
but when I try it as `import cv2` in IDLE terminal, then It gives error as

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installed OpenCV but no module found "cv2" in IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132864/installed-opencv-but-no-module-found-cv2-in-idle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Download OpenCV from [here](https://opencv.org/opencv-3-4-1.html)

2)Extract the zip file to Root drive(mostly 'C'Drive)

3)Goto folder `opencv\build\python\2.7\x86` and copy `cv2` file to your main Python directory,

in my case Python directory is

`C:\Users\Deshmukh Brothers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages`

and paste cv2 file there.

4)Run command as `python -m idlelib` and now it will prompt idle-shell.

5)now it will work as `import cv2`, it nothing occurred and cursor went to next line then it is successfully installed.

Answer (score 3):

You could also install **opencv** in these three easy steps

1. Type **py -m pip install opencv-python**
2. In the same window type **python** or open IDLE python.
3. Now type **import cv2**.
   there you go... simple and easy i hope it helps.