# import cv2 work on IDLE but error on command prompt

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

The issue is exactly opposite of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49516989/import-cv2-doesnt-give-error-on-command-prompt-but-error-on-idle-on-windows-10?noredirect=1&lq=1) issue.

I have installed OpenCV as mentioned in its documentation on windows 10.
(Copying a file into python lib directory).

When I import cv2 from the python IDLE, its working fine but when I use command prompt or Powershell it doesn't work. I'm not using anaconda or Jupiter-notebook or something else as deployment.

What is the issue here..?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshots `IDLE` is running Python `2.7.13`, while in `CMD` you're on `3.6.4`.

These versions have separate `lib` folders, so you should check whether you installed OpenCV properly on both versions.

Or just stick with Python 2 on CMD.